# Microsoft Project views

Tags: ms-project

I'm pretty new to Microsoft Project and I'm trying to put several views in place. However, for some reason, if I edit one view (Issue Log view) my Gantt Chart view gets the same updates. So if I remove columns in one, the other gets the same column removed. Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add or subtract columns you are changing the *table* which is part of the view.  I suggest making custom tables to apply to the custom views.  You don't note which version of Project - so assuming you are using 2013 or later: Click the View Ribbon and open the Tables drop down in the Data group.  Choose "Save Fields as New Table".  The custom table should now be part of the view.  Apply the Entry table and reset it to the default.  Many views in Project use the default entry table.

Comment: Thanks Julie! It's 2010 I'm using (unfortunately), but the same solution applies.

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to know you have it sorted.